# Response header Set-Cookie doesn't store cookies in browser

Tags: browser, setcookie

I'm setting 2 cookies in response from backend to the browser.
One that is secure HTTPOnly (it's refreshToken) and the other one without those parameters so it's accessible to JavaScript (carrying information about refreshToken is set and when it expires).

Cookies in response:

[image]

Neither of those two is set in browser. I studied all about cookies and I'll be honest, I'm lost here and need your help.

At first it was working very well on my localhost environment (backend on localhost:8080, frontend on localhost:3000).
Then I made deploy and there it was NOT working.
I tested again on localhost and I checked "Disable cache" to prevent unwanted behaviour and it is not working even there.

I'll mention that I'm using CORS, not sure if that can may interfere:

[image]

I tested this both in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I FINALY figured it out. Cookies are valid. The answer is to set **withCredentials = true** both in frontend and backend.

First I thought the parameter **withCredentials on frontend** is used only when we want to send our credentials hidden in secure HttpOnly cookies to which we don't have access to but browser does.
Apparently it is also used when we want to set cookies from response. [Link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

> responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request

Secondly, we also have to add **withCredentials on backend** to **CorsFilter** (in Spring boot) otherwise we get CORS error.

```kotlin
CorsConfiguration()
    .apply {
        allowedOrigins = listOf(uiUrl)
        allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
        allowedMethods = listOf("*")
        allowCredentials = true
    }
```

Comment: Wish I'd have seen this sooner. YOU SAVED MY DAY :)

Comment: This is the clearest answer, because to address the issue, you need to take care `both front-end and back-end`. Many answers failed to do so and causing more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> I FINALY figured it out. Cookies are valid. The answer is to set withCredentials = true both in frontend and backend.

I had the same issue.

On the frontend (127.0.0.1:3000), I am using Axios and I needed this:

```
 return axios
    .post(
        API_LOGIN,
        {
            email,
            password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
    ).then(....).catch(....);
```

On the backend, I am using NestJS and I needed this:

```
  app.enableCors({
     credentials: true,
     origin: APP_URL,
     exposedHeaders: ['set-cookie','ajax_redirect'],
     preflightContinue: true,
     methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
     optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  });
```